# Docker does not find file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV KERNEL /kernel-git
ENV IMAGEDIR /buildroot-git
ENV SYZKALLER /syzkaller-git
ENV SYZKALLER_WORKDIR /syzkaller_workdir
ENV SYZKALLER_DIR $SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/
ENV SYZKALLER_BIN $SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/bin/

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
WORKDIR .
COPY rootfs.ext3 /buildroot-git/rootfs.ext3
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu && apt-get -y install vim subversion snapd build-essential flex bison libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 \
       linux-libc-dev libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev git debootstrap qemu-system-aarch64 wget sed make binutils gcc g++ bash patch gzip bzip2 perl tar cpio unzip rsync file bc wget git fakeroot build-essential ncurses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc flex libelf-dev bison
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-VERSION.tar.xz 
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  apt update && apt -y install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu golang-go && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  mkdir $KERNEL && tar -xf linux-VERSION.tar.xz -C $KERNEL && cd $KERNEL/linux-VERSION          && \
    ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make defconfig && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KCOV=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KCOV /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_INLINE=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_OUTLINE=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_OUTLINE /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_INLINE /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_INLINE=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KCOV_INSTRUMENT_ALL=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KCOV_INSTRUMENT_ALL /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_DEBUG_FS /d' .config && \   
    sed -i '/CONFIG_NET_9P=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_NET_9P /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_CMDLINE=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_CMDLINE /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KASAN=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KASAN /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_CONSTRUCTORS=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_CONSTRUCTORS /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_VMAP_STACK=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_VMAP_STACK /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_STACKDEPOT=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_STACKDEPOT /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_EXTRA=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_KASAN_EXTRA /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_TEST_KASAN=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_TEST_KASAN /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_STACKDEPOT=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_STACKDEPOT /d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_STACKTRACE=/d' .config && \
    sed -i '/CONFIG_STACKTRACE /d' .config && \
    printf 'CONFIG_KCOV=y\nCONFIG_KASAN=y\nCONFIG_KASAN_INLINE=y\nCONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KASAN=y\nCONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y\nCONFIG_CMDLINE="console=ttyAMA0"\nCONFIG_KCOV_INSTRUMENT_ALL=y\nCONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y\nCONFIG_NET_9P=y\nCONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO=y\nCONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-linux-gnu-"\nCONFIG_CONSTRUCTORS=y\nCONFIG_VMAP_STACK=y\nCONFIG_STACKDEPOT=y\nCONFIG_KASAN_EXTRA=y\n# CONFIG_KASAN_OUTLINE is not set\nCONFIG_TEST_KASAN=m\n#CONFIG_STACKTRACE is not set\n' >> .config && \
        yes | make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- oldconfig && \
    ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make -j$(nproc) && \
    mkdir $SYZKALLER && cd $SYZKALLER \
    mkdir gopath && \
    export GOPATH=`pwd`/gopath && \
    export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH && \
    go get -u -d github.com/google/syzkaller/prog && \
    cd $SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/ && \
    make && printf '{\n    "name": "QEMU-aarch64",\n    "target": "linux/arm64",\n    "http": ":56700",\n    "workdir": "$SYZKALLER_WORKDIR",\n    "syzkaller": "$SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/",\n    "image": "$IMAGEDIR/rootfs.ext3",\n    "procs": 8,\n    "type": "qemu",\n    "vm": {\n        "count": 1,\n        "qemu": "qemu-system-aarch64",\n        "cmdline": "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/vda",\n        "kernel": "$KERNEL/arm64/boot/Image",\n        "cpu": 2,\n        "mem": 2048\n    }\n}\n' >> $SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/arm64.conf && \
    ./syzkaller-git/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/bin/syz-manager -config $SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/arm64.conf
```

As you can see, I'm compiling a go application.
When I'm trying to run the last command it fails with this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1:  /syzkaller-git/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/bin/syz-manager: not found
```

I've checked if the file is really exists and it does.
Tried to look online but nothing helped.
I've also tried to seperate this specific command from the one-lined RUN command, but it didn't help.

Comment: "I've checked if the file is really exists"... How did you check? Please include the commands you've run and their output. What is the command you're trying to run, a binary or shell script. If the former, include ldd output on the binary. If the latter, include the first line showing the interpreter and verify the linefeed type of the file (Windows or Linux).

Answer (score 0):

You are already at this path `$SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/`

Dockerfile

```
cd $SYZKALLER/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/ && \
```

and you are trying to access the file in that path

```
./syzkaller-git/gopath/src/github.com/google/syzkaller/bin/syz-manager
```

It seems that you need to update the above to be either an absolute path or use the command like

```
./bin/syz-manager
```